# connected list controls

Tags: javascript, jquery

sorry for my English google translator. I have three connected lists

```
$( ".listaAvisosConectados" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".listaAvisosConectados",
    dropOnEmpty:true,

    }).disableSelection();
```

Example online: http://test.vertudemo.com/

and I need to implement any element can be added on the red list but that list items can not be green or blue added in opposing lists. Red accepts all. Green only accepts green and blue only blue.

I've tried several ways but cannot do it.

If I put a different class to each list green and red. Red List and add two classes do not work very well.

Answer (score 0):

looks like there is a "cancel" method you can use in response to a "receive" event-- e.g. (in pseudocode)

```
bluelist.sortable(
recieve: function(event, ui){
if(ui.element.class == "green"){ //I don't remember exactly how to get the element off the top of my head, but I think it's something like ui.element
$(this).sortable('cancel');
}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried but does not work, I think that the receive function is executed after the item was received, I leave here a new example at least able to identify in what condition I have to not accept the item

Comment: $( ".listaAvisosConectados" ).sortable({
connectWith: ".listaAvisosConectados",
dropOnEmpty:true,
receive: function(event, ui) { 
 if (($(ui.item).hasClass('itemBlue'))&&($(this).hasClass('greenList'))) {    
  alert("ItemBlue in GreenList");
  $(this).sortable('cancel');
 }

  if (($(ui.item).hasClass('itemGreen'))&&($(this).hasClass('blueList'))) {    
       alert("ItemGreen in BlueList"); 
  $(this).sortable('cancel');
 }
                
}}).disableSelection();

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see you added it to the demo. Hm... can you put your demo in a js fiddle? It would be easier to help you if I can manipulate things myself.